# How do I query a JSON datatype from postgresql with clojure.java.jdbc?

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jdbc, clojure

I understand how to:

- [Query JSON in Postgres](http://schinckel.net/2014/05/25/querying-json-in-postgres/)
- [How to query JSON data from postgresql in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655731/how-to-query-data-which-is-json-datatype-from-postgresql-in-sqlalchemy)
- [how to use clojure.java.jdbc](https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc)

But I don't know how to put it together and query json with clojure.java.jdbc.

For example, I have a table user, and a field user_info

```
CREATE TABLE user (id SERIAL,user_info JSON);
```

then I found [this blog](http://www.niwi.be/2014/04/13/postgresql-json-field-with-clojure-and-jdbc/) to impl some protocol,and it insert success!

```
(insert! conn :yxt_user {:user_info {:hello [1 "test" true]}})
```

But I don't know how to write code to query it like this sql from jdbc/query

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE data ? 'hello';
```

not by jdbc/execute direct write sql like

```
(jdbc/execute! db-spec ["UPDATE table SET col1 = NOW() WHERE id = ?" 77])
```

I tried to write this query

```
(jdbc/query conn ["SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_info ? 'hello'"])
```

I got this

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 未设定参数值 1 的内容。
```

Then I tried

```
(jdbc/query conn ["SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_info ? 'hello'" "?"])
```

I got this

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
```

How do I write a query to filter on a JSON column where user_info has the JSON key `hello`?

Comment: Can you please describe, both for the select and the update, the code you are trying to run and the error message you get?

Comment: because some  error message is chinese,i am afraid you don't understand.

Comment: What is `userinfo ? 'hello'` supposed to do? Do you mean `userinfo = 'hello'`? In the JSON field?

Comment: no,it is postgresql json query grammar,it means all json which has key `hello` http://schinckel.net/2014/05/25/querying-json-in-postgres/

Comment: So then it's probably confusing the first '?' with '?' as a placeholder? I don't believe you can use placeholders to insert operators, which might be what you are trying to do. Have you tried escaping the '?'?

Comment: I'd suggest asking this as a JDBC question alone, with the Clojure aspects filtered out, to get the widest range of responses.

Comment: This is, by the way, very close to (if not a duplicate of) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779896/does-the-jdbc-spec-prevent-from-being-used-as-an-operator-outside-of-quotes

Comment: Personally, I would consider writing the query to call `json_object_keys()` and filter on its output -- if you don't care about performance -- or creating a stored procedure that encapsulates the syntax you need -- if you do.

Comment: yes，I think it is very http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779896/does-the-jdbc-spec-prevent-from-being-used-as-an-operator-outside-of-quotes it is my wey of search is stubborn.can't find that question.thanks

Comment: I am not sure though if they already introduced a workaround in the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the latest postgresql driver you can escape the ? with a double ??

This should work:

```
 (jdbc/query conn ["SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_info ?? 'hello'"])
```